# Embedding pyplot graph into html on django framework

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I am new to python and Django but have a bit of code that works in displaying my graph but as a separate popup window. I am calling this line of code from my HTML page:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Title: {{ report.title }}</h1>

<div>
{{ report.show_graph }}  //THIS PORTION IS CALLING THE GRAPH WHICH IS RESULTING IN A POPUP OF IT IN A SEPARATE WINDOW
</div>

<p><strong>Summary:</strong> {{ report.summary }}</p>
<p>Date Created: {{ report.date_created }}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

It triggers a request and calls the graph but as a separate standalone window.
The code I am calling is:

```
class Report(models.Model):
"""Model representing a report"""
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
date_created = models.DateField("Date", default=datetime.date.today)
summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Enter a brief summary of the report.')

def __str__(self):
    """String for representing the Model Object"""
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    """Returns the url to access a digital record of this Report"""
    return reverse('report-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

def show_graph(self):
    style.use('ggplot')
    pfizer_data = quandl.get("NSE/PFIZER", authtoken="....")
    pfizer_data['Close'].plot()
    return plt.show()
```

I am trying to have the graph be returned as HTML so it is embedded in the div instead of a separate window. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think matplotlib writes HTML. You need to write the HTML yourself.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? I found a library called mpld3 and it allows me to convert it to html. When I return the code of html it converts to, it does not properly display which I am starting to get lost in.

Comment: What do you mean by _"not properly display"_?

Comment: I ended up solving my own question. With mpld3.fig_to_html, the call was returning the html text instead of the graph. I found another thread linked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924890/django-rendering-matplotlib-chart-in-html-using-mpld3

Comment: @HassanEid I though you wanted a static image. If you want help with mpld3 be specific describing your issue in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Well I tried with the library **mpld3** that you mention. It uses **jinja2**, so you have to install it, but there's no need to add it in `settings.py BACKEND`. Here's an example of what I accomplish:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3
import numpy as np

from django.shortcuts import render


def matplotlib_graph(request):

    # HERE I USE AN EXMAMPLE FROM MATPLOTLIB SITE

    # Data for plotting
    t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
    s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(t, s)

    ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
           title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
    ax.grid()
    g = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)
    fig.savefig("test.png")

    context = {'g': g}

    return render(request, 'myhtml.html', context)
```

And in the html template:

```
<h1>My graph</h1>

{% autoescape off %}
<div>{{ g }}</div>
{% endautoescape %}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Took a different route and used mpld3 library. Reference to alternate solution: [Django Rendering Matplotlib chart in HTML using mpld3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924890/django-rendering-matplotlib-chart-in-html-using-mpld3)